# DropDownList.Items.Add and AppendDataBoundItems does not appear to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

When I run this, I am getting the error: 'ddlExpCode1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
The value of the SelectedValue is "-1" which you can clearly see being added here.

I have set AppendDataBoundItems to "True".

Why is it erroring?

```
string strExpCode = ddlExpCode1.SelectedValue.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

ddlExpCode1.Items.Clear();
ddlExpCode1.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls .ListItem("Please select", "-1"));

ddlExpCode1.DataSource = expCodes;
ddlExpCode1.DataTextField = "displayExpenseCode";
ddlExpCode1.DataValueField = "ID";
ddlExpCode1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception? You don't set the `SelectedValue` above.

Comment: Can you show a larger portion of the code? In what method do you do this? If you reset the items in `Page_Load` maybe you`re missing a `!IsPostback`?

Comment: The selected value is correct. Why is it erroring?

Comment: Maybe on the `postback` you are loosing this value. If you show more code, we can see and help.

Comment: The selected value is correct. Why is it erroring?

Answer (score 0):

Data bind first before you add items

```
 ddlExpCode1.DataTextField = "displayExpenseCode";
 ddlExpCode1.DataValueField = "ID";
 ddlExpCode1.DataSource = expCodes;
 ddlExpCode1.DataBind();


 ddlExpCode1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select", "0"));
```

Second option is in page declartion

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlExpCode1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="[ Please select ]" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
```

`AppendDataBoundItems="true"` is the key.